# Error while getting select box value with php

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am currently working on a project where a user chooses an option from a select box and submits a form, the form is then processed by PHP, and the PHP code determines what the select box value is, and does something based on that value.

My select box is called `combined_group` and has two select values: `philharmonic_orchestra` and `symphony_orchestra`.

This is how I am checking the selected value:

```
if($_POST['combined_group'] == "philharmonic_orchestra"){
    $_SESSION['semesterprice'] = "170";
    $_SESSION['fullprice'] = "330";
}
if($_POST['combined_group'] == "symphony_orchestra"){
    $_SESSION['semesterprice'] = "275";
    $_SESSION['fullprice'] = "530";
}
```

But when PHP runs through this code, neither `if` statement is chosen. I know that the value of `$_POST['combined_group']` is, in fact, either of those two values, just PHP isn't picking it up for some reason.

Anybody care to help?

**EDIT:** My HTML form code is as follows

```
<select name="combined_group" class="OBJ-1">
<option value="" selected="">Select One</option>
<option value="philharmonic_orchestra">Philharmonic Orchestra</option>
<option value="symphony_orchestra ">Symphony Orchestra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post the html code where you define the select box?

Comment: What do you get if you run `var_dump($_POST['combined_group']);`? Also, it might be useful to add your HTML code code as well.

Comment: You have empty space here: value="symphony_orchestra "

Comment: If generated dynamically, your option values must be escaped either in html or php. Unless you added the space accidentally. Answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Client side**

```
<select name="combined_group">
<option value="">Select an option</option>
<option value="philharmonic_orchestra">Philharmonic Orchestra</option>
<option value="symphony_orchestra">Symphony Orchestra</option>
</select>
```

**Server side**

```
if (! isset($_POST["combined_group"]))
{
   exit('not set');
}
if (trim($_POST["combined_group"]) == '')
{
   exit('not selected');
}
if (trim($_POST["combined_group"]) == 'philharmonic_orchestra')
{
   //business logic for 'philharmonic_orchestra'
}
else
{
   //business logic for 'symphony_orchestra'
}
```

Comment: Seems like `trim()` fixed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is a bad HTML syntax. Check if your option item has value attribute:

```
<option value="...">...</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your conditional statement is failing, is because of a space in your option's value.

```
<option value="symphony_orchestra ">
                                 ^ right there
```

What you will need to do is remove it:

```
<option value="symphony_orchestra">
                                 ^ deleted space
```

---

***Technical sidenote:***

Had your conditional statement been:

```
if($_POST['combined_group'] == "symphony_orchestra ")
                                                  ^ notice the space
```

with the space before the quote, it would have worked.

- Anything between quotes is considered and part of an element's value.